# Stein, Algebraic Number Theory, Proposition 2.4.5

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation, finitely-generated

In Stein's proof of propositions 2.4.5 on page 25 of [A Computational Approach to Algebraic Number Theory](http://wstein.org/books/ant/ant.pdf) at the end he makes the claim that $\mathcal{O}_K$ has finite index in
$$
A = \frac{1}{d}\mathbb{Z}\cdot a_1 + \cdots + \frac{1}{d}\mathbb{Z}\cdot a_n \cong \mathbb{Z}^n
$$
and then states that because of this $\mathcal{O}_K$ is free of rank $n$. Why does $\mathcal{O}_K$ not have any torsion?

Comment: Every non-identity element of a free abelian group has infinite order.

Comment: Any submodule of a torsion-free module is also necessarily torsion-free, and $A$ is clearly torsion-free (though as quasi notes, any free abelian group is torsion-free). The point here is that over a PID, any submodule of a free module of rank $n$ is free of rank $\leqslant n$. The only way that $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ could have rank $< n$ is if it had infinite index in $A$, but it doesn't.